# Keras Conv1d Input Shape: Error when checking input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using keras with TF backend to build a simple `Conv1d` net. The data has the following shape:

```
train feature shape: (33960, 3053, 1)
train label shape: (33960, 686, 1)
```

I build my model with:

```
def create_conv_model():

    inp =  Input(shape=(3053, 1))
    conv = Conv1D(filters=2, kernel_size=2)(inp)
    pool = MaxPool1D(pool_size=2)(conv)
    flat = Flatten()(pool)
    dense = Dense(686)(flat)
    model = Model(inp, dense)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

    return model
```

Model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 3053, 1)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 3052, 2)           6         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 1526, 2)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 3052)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 686)               2094358   
=================================================================
Total params: 2,094,364
Trainable params: 2,094,364
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Upon running

```
model.fit(x=train_feature,
    y=train_label_categorical,
    epochs=100,
    batch_size=64,
    validation_split=0.2,
    validation_data=(test_feature,test_label_categorical),
    callbacks=[tensorboard,reduce_lr,early_stopping])
```

i get the following VERY USUAL ERROR:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8491, 3053)
```

I've checked pretty much all the posts regarding this very common problem, but I've been unable to find a solution. What am i doing wrong? I don't understand what's going on. Where is the shape `(8491, 3053)` coming from?

Any help will be much appreciated, I am not able to make this go away.

Comment: Could you please double check and print the shape of training and validation data, i.e. `print(train_feature.shape)` and `print(test_feature.shape)`?

Comment: Further (this is not relevant to the error), you should either use `validation_split` or `validation_data`, and not both.

Comment: print(train_feature.shape,train_label_categorical.shape) immediately prior to model.fit():
(33960, 3053, 1) (33960, 686)

Comment: And what about the validation data?

Comment: For now it's the same as testing data...

Comment: OK, what about testing data, i.e. `test_feature.shape`?

Comment: test_feature, test_label shapes:

(8491, 3053) (8491, 686)

YES!! THANK YOU! This is it, i am sure!!

Comment: Please read my comments carefully: I am looking for **test** data shape, not **training**'s. Please just run `print(test_feature.shape)`.

Comment: Yeah, there you have it.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! i was blind to this...

Comment: shouldn't your train label shape be (33960, 686) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `validation_data=(test_feature,test_label_categorical)` in `model.fit` function  to

`validation_data=(np.expand_dims(test_feature, -1),test_label_categorical)`

The model is expecting validation feature of shape `(8491, 3053, 1)`, but in above code you are providing it `(8491, 3053)`.